# "run on server" on java dynamic web project brings 404

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache, cxf

Choosing "run on server" on apache tomcat 7 brings 404 error page up on eclipse. Going through the browser does the same. Any known solution?
Im using cxf on apache tomcat 7 . 
Note :  already tryed "changing server location" solution.

Comment: Is your project well formed ? No errors listed in the logs ?

Comment: Only one warning .  "Ws-i: A problem occured while running the ws-i wsdl conformance check... " but I dont think that is the issue.

Comment: Apache 7? I'm assuming you mean Tomcat 7.

Comment: do you reach tomcat home page at least? localhost:8080 or 8084 depending on configuration..

Comment: Yes i do, but only when I change the server location.

Comment: what does server output says upon starting? any error/not nice things displayed? give us more information please.. by the way did you searched for the warning you have?

Comment: By the way, could you explain what do you mean by 'changing the server location' ?

Comment: There are no exceptions or warnings on server startup. By saying that I've "changed the server location" I meant in the server properties i choosed "use tomcat installation" instead of "workspace metadata". Did it to fix the loading of the server web pages (main and etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the most recent CXF Plugins for eclipse solved the problem.
In the future if you are expiriancing the same problem , look over here:
[Installing CXF on exlipse](http://cxf.apache.org/setting-up-eclipse.html).
Look under: "Required plugins" , istall them all.
Seems like it fixed the "Ws-i: A problem occured while running the ws-i wsdl conformance check... "  messege.